# How to disable teleport Steam VR/Unity for one controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steam, steamvr

The goal is to teleport with only one controller.

Should it be done via **Action Sets** or could it be done via **Event Trigger**?
I could not find anything specific related to the controllers in the *Hand* script also.

Using the **Action Sets** should I use the **per hand** option and customize which settings? Then, how could I create I field in the Inspector?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting a reference to your controllers `SteamVR_Behaviour_Pose` component and just check if it is the controller you want to do the teleporting with. `SteamVR_Input_Sources`is a enum that is used to identify your vive hardware.

```
public SteamVR_Behaviour_Pose pose;

if(pose.inputSource == SteamVR_Input_Sources.LeftHand)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Be careful tho. I don't quite remember but I think this can cause a `NullReferenceException`if the hardware you are trying to access is not connected.

You could also, as you already thought about, use the **ActionSets** and use different actions for both hands. That **should** also work, I just never tried it.

As a bonus:

```
public SteamVR_Action_Boolean action = SteamVR_Input.GetBooleanAction("YourActionName");

if (action.GetStateUp(pose.inputSource))
{
    //do even more stuff
}
```

Thats how you check for actions in your script. Took me a long time of reading docs to find out myself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try them soon!